# How to calculate number of events per day using python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, events

I am having problems calculating/counting the number of events per day using python. I have a .txt file of earthquake data that I am using to do this. Here is what the file looks like:

```
2000 Jan 19 00 21 45 -118.815670 37.533170 3.870000 2.180000 383.270000 
2000 Jan 11 16 16 46 -118.804500 37.551330 5.150000 2.430000 380.930000 
2000 Jan 11 19 55 54 -118.821830 37.508830 0.600000 2.360000 378.080000
2000 Jan 11 05 33 02 -118.802000 37.554670 4.820000 2.530000 375.480000
2000 Jan 08 19 37 04 -118.815500 37.534670 3.900000 2.740000 373.650000
2000 Jan 09 19 34 27 -118.817670 37.529670 3.990000 3.170000 373.07000
```

Where column 0 is the year, 1 is the month, 2 is the day. There are no headers.

I want to calculate/count the number of events per day. Each line in the file (example: 2000 Jan 11) is an event. So, On January 11th, I would like to know how many times there was an event. In this case, on January 11th, there were 3 events.

I've tried looking on stack for some guidance and have found code that works for arrays such as:

```
a = [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

which counts the occurrence of certain items in the array using code like:

```
unique, counts = numpy.unique(a, return_counts=True)
dict(zip(unique, counts))
```

I have not been able to find anything that helps me. Any help/advice would be appreciated.

Comment: In this case you could ignore that it is a database and do a count of unique values for the first 11 characters of each line.

Answer (score 1):

[groupby()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) is going to be your friend here. However, I would concatenate the Year, Month and Day so that you can use `dataframe.groupby(["full_date"]).count()`

**Full solution**

- Setup DF

`df = pd.DataFrame([[2000, "Jan", 19],[2000, "Jan", 20],[2000, "Jan", 19],[2000, "Jan", 19]], columns = ["Year", "Month", "Day"])`

- Convert datatypes to str for concatenation

`df["Year"] = df["Year"].astype(str)
 df["Day"] = df["Day"].astype(str)`

- Create 'full_date' column

`df["full_date"] = df["Year"] + "-" + df["Month"] + "-" + df["Day"]`

- Count the # of days

`df.groupby(["full_date"])["Day"].count()`

Hope this helps/provides value :)